# Call function every time ng-show is true?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, angular-strap

I'm currently using AngularStrap tabs in a project, and I want the content for one of the tabs to be refreshed every time the tab is shown. I have the tabs set up with

```
%div(ng-model="tabs.index" bs-tabs="tabs")
  %div(ng-repeat="tab in tabs" data-title="{{tab}}")
```

and the tab is shown using

```
%div(ng-show="tabs.active().title == 'Previous Requests'")
  %div(class="outer-tab-content")
```

However, since ng-show just displays the tab, and doesn't load it every time it's shown, I can't seem to use ng-load to solve this problem. And, since I'm using AngularStrap tabs, I can't figure out how to add an ng-onclick to the tab in question.

Advice?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle that illustrates your issue?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure how to create a fiddle for this? There isn't actually something that is loading incorrectly; I just don't know Angular well enough to figure out whether there is a directive I can use to load a script every time ng-show is true (or, every time "tabs.active().title == 'Previous Requests'"). And, Googling + checking the index of O'Reilly's AngularJS book hasn't helped much, either...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a watch for your active tab title in your controller code:

```
$scope.$watch('tabs.active.active().title', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if(newValue === 'Previous Requests') 
        $scope.tabs.refresh();
});
```